# Multiple columns update using single case expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, case

Is it possible to update multiple columns with a single case statement or does the case statement have to be repeated for each column? I need to update two columns that both use the same case criteria and would like to do it all in one case statement. Is this possible? Here’s an example of what I’m trying to do using two case expression :

```
UPDATE #wrkcd
SET topdate = CASE 
                 WHEN stopdate < @currentdate AND wustopcd = 'W' THEN stopdate
                 WHEN stopdate > @currentdate AND minstopdate < @currentdate THEN @currentdate
                 WHEN stopdate > @currentdate AND minstopdate > @currentdate AND minstopdate < stopdate THEN minstopdate
                 WHEN stopdate < minstopdate AND wustopcd <> 'W' THEN minstopdate
                 ELSE stopdate
              END,
   wustopcd = CASE
                 WHEN stopdate < @currentdate AND wustopcd = 'W' THEN wustopcd
                 WHEN stopdate > @currentdate AND minstopdate < @currentdate THEN minwustopcd
                 WHEN stopdate > @currentdate AND minstopdate > @currentdate AND minstopdate < stopdate THEN minwustopcd
                 WHEN stopdate < minstopdate AND wustopcd <> 'W' THEN minwustopcd
                 ELSE wustopcd
              END
```

Thanks for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: No. One column per CASE expr.

Comment: It's a case **expression**, not a statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use `values` construct to evaluate as single expression :

```
update t
     set t.topdate = tt.stopdate,
         t.wustopcd = tt.stopdate
from #wrkcd t cross apply
     ( values (CASE WHEN stopdate < @currentdate AND wustopcd = 'W' THEN stopdate
                    WHEN stopdate > @currentdate AND minstopdate < @currentdate THEN @currentdate
                    WHEN stopdate > @currentdate AND minstopdate > @currentdate AND minstopdate < stopdate THEN minstopdate
                    WHEN stopdate < minstopdate AND wustopcd <> 'W' THEN minstopdate
                    ELSE stopdate
               END)
     ) tt(stopdate);
```